# Test Coverage only 56%

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

I have the following test class that is only getting 56% coverage on my trigger. The trigger assigns numbers to the Account object. Any suggestions on improving my test coverage?

```
trigger AccountNumberIndex on Opportunity(before insert,before update){

    List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();

    for(Opportunity opp:trigger.new){

        if(opp.AccountId!=null){

            accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
        }
    }

    Map<Id,Account> accMap = new Map<Id,Account>([select id,LC_Region__c,AccountNumber 
                                              from Account where id in:accIds]);

    Counterr__c value = new Counterr__c(Ones__c = 101000);

    for(Counterr__c record:[SELECT Id,Ones__c FROM Counterr__c FOR UPDATE]) {

        value = record;

        for(Opportunity opp :trigger.new){

            if(!accMap.IsEmpty()){

                if((opp.Probability == 90) && (accMap.get(opp.AccountId).AccountNumber == null)){

                    if(accMap.get(opp.AccountId).LC_Region__c == 'North America'){

                        accMap.get(opp.AccountId).AccountNumber = '0'.repeat(math.max(0,0-String.valueOf(value.Ones__c).length()))+String.valueOf(value.Ones__c);

                        value.Ones__c+= 1;
                    }
                    update value;
                }
                update accMap.values();
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Here is my test class so far...

```
@isTest
private class UnitTests_AccountNumberIndex {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        //Setup accNumber record
        Counterr__c Count = new Counterr__c();
        Count.Name = 'Counterr';
        Count.Ones__c=101000;
        insert Count;

        // Setup the Account record
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'test account';
        acc.LC_Region__c = '--None--';
        acc.AccountNumber =null;

        insert acc;

        // Setup the Opportunity record
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'test opp';
        opp.Probability = 50;

        insert opp;

        test.startTest();

        opp.Probability = 90;

        update opp;

        acc.LC_Region__c = 'North America';

        update acc;

        Count.Ones__c=101001;

        update Count;

        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you think you're properly creating your accounts, opportunities and other objects according to their relationships? An opportunity is a child of account, but you've not related your opp to your account. Similarly, create your other relationships BEFORE your trigger runs like `LC_Region__c` which appears to be a custom field on Account. Should it really be 'none' at the start of your test? Its your test, so I don't know.

When you stop your test, its important that you assert what values you expect. Its not clear to me if that's what you were attempting to do with `Count.Ones__c=101001;` just before the end of your test since that's a custom object that I'm not entirely certain what's its purpose is and don't have a lot of time to spare figuring it out.

The only way to test `if(!accMap.IsEmpty()){` is to add a method where the accMap is indeed empty!

Finally, I see that you're only testing with one account. In this type of trigger, I'd expect to see a test class with an array of accounts and opportunities. However, I recognize you do have to start someplace.

Answer (score 0):

First assign AccountId from acc to the Opportunity opp as mentioned above.

```
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(AccountId = acc.Id, Name = 'test opp', Probability = 50);
```